# C# Runtime Error: "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid"

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I've been working most of the day on this, and the solution continues to elude me.  My Winform application contains a `DataGridView` wherein two of the columns are `ComboBox` dropdown lists.  Oddly, the `DataGridView` appears to populate correctly, but it throws up a plethora of errors while populating or whenever there is a mouseover or seemingly any other triggerable event related to the `DataGridVeiw`.  Specifically, I am getting two repeating errors for `System.ArgumentException` and `System.FormatException`.  The message text for both of these errors is:

> "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid. To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event."

I don't want to merely mask this problem by handling the `DataError` event.  *I want to resolve the issue that is causing error.*  This is how I am populating the list:

```
class ManageProcsRecord
{
    public SectionType PageSection { get; set; }
    public Int32 ContentID { get; set; }
    public String Content { get; set; }
    public Int32 SummaryID { get; set; }
    public RoleType UserRole { get; set; }
    public String Author { get; set; }
    public String SysTime { get; set; }
}

public enum SectionType
{
    ESJP_SECTION_HEADER = 1,
    ESJP_SECTION_FOOTER,
    ESJP_SECTION_BODY
}

public enum RoleType
{
    ESJP_ROLE_NONE = 1,
    ESJP_ROLE_TEST_ENG,
    ESJP_ROLE_FEATURE_LEAD,
    ESJP_ROLE_TEAM_LEAD
}

List<ManageProcsRecord> records =
    this.dbif.GetProcedure(this.procList.ElementAt(selectedIndex).PrimaryKey);

foreach (ManageProcsRecord record in records)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
    row.CreateCells(this.dataGridView1);
    row.Cells[0].ValueType = typeof(SectionType);
    row.Cells[0].Value = record.PageSection;
    row.Cells[1].Value = record.Content;
    row.Cells[2].Value = (record.SummaryID != -1);
    row.Cells[3].ValueType = typeof(RoleType);
    row.Cells[3].Value = record.UserRole;
    row.Cells[4].Value = record.Author;
    row.Cells[5].Value = record.SysTime;
    this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);     // error fest starts here
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to resolve this are much appreciatd!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didnt explain how the DGV got populated, but I will assume you did a design time setup.  If you typed in the names/data from those Enums, they will be typed as strings so you get a match error.  Populate it using the Enum and set the Type as such and it wont yell at you:

```
List<ProcRecord> Records = new List<ProcRecord>();

// add some records
Records.Add(new ProcRecord()
{
    Author = "Ziggy",
    PageSection = SectionType.ESJP_SECTION_BODY,
    UserRole = RoleType.ESJP_ROLE_FEATURE_LEAD
});
Records.Add(new ProcRecord()
{
    Author = "Zalgo",
    PageSection = SectionType.ESJP_SECTION_BODY,
    UserRole = RoleType.ESJP_ROLE_FEATURE_LEAD
});

// set cbo datasources
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgv1.Columns[0];
col.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SectionType));
col.ValueType = typeof(SectionType);

col = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgv1.Columns[4];
col.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(RoleType));
col.ValueType = typeof(RoleType);
```

If you have a list of those things, there is no need to manually copy them one by one into the control.  Just bind the `List` to the DGV. Edits to the data in the control will flow thru to the List:

```
dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
// Show Me the RECORDS!!!!
dgv1.DataSource = Records;
```

[image]

Your next obstacle is likely to be getting `SysTime` to display and act like a Date or Time (if that is what it is) since it is defined as string.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  I think the problem was in how I was setting the column `DataSource`.