# Replace int column in Data Table with combobox for DataGridView (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataTable with some integer values (assume 0 => 'open', 1 => 'proceeding', 2 => 'free' etc.) and in a dgv I want to allow the user to change that value, but with a combobox and with string values. So I created to test this a simple winform app

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("test");
        dt.Rows.Add(1);
        dt.Rows.Add(2);

        DataTable source = new DataTable();
        source.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("Value", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Display", typeof(string)) });
        source.Rows.Add(0, "zero");
        source.Rows.Add(1, "one");
        source.Rows.Add(2, "two");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        var testTextColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        testTextColumn.HeaderText = "Text";
        testTextColumn.Name = "testText";
        testTextColumn.DataSource = source;
        testTextColumn.DisplayMember = "Display";
        testTextColumn.ValueMember = "Value";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(testTextColumn);
    }
```

So far so good, I thought I could simply make the test column invisible and only have the testText column visible (in the final app), but how does one combine the to values, i.e. when I change something in the cb update the value of the datatable? I could do it by changeEvents, but that seems rather impractical. Is there some sort of databinding?

[image: Exmple dgv]

Comment: With a combo column you almost always have a conversion involved - translate what the users sees/picks into whatever you want to save.  Eg convert `Stooges.Moe` in the cbo to `1` for storage in the DB.  That partly comes from the type or data used in the cbo, but also the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties to provide the mapping.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39252169/1070452 also may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37848426/1070452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three (3) things wrong in your posted code to achieve what you describe.

1-The line of code…

```
dt.Columns.Add("test");
```

… is defaulting to a `string` value. Therefore, the combo box would throw a `DataError` when you try to bind the “Value” column from the `source` table. So, you need to specify the `int` type column in the data. Like…

```
dt.Columns.Add("test", typeof(int));
```

2- Before the code set the grids `DataSource` the code needs to specify that we do NOT want the grid to `AutoGenerateColumns`. Otherwise, we will end up with two columns. In addition, this grid property is NOT a displayed property in the “Designer.” You will need to set this property BEFORE you add the data source and you need to set this property in your code. Something like…

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

3- When the code creates the combo box column, it never identifies “which” column in the grids `DataSource` we want to bind the combo box column to. That is the purpose of the columns `DataPropertyName`. So, you need to add this line of code in the combo box definition…

```
testTextColumn.DataPropertyName = "test";
```

Making these changes, should display only the combo box column.

Comment: Perfect!! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

creates a cell change event, then takes the number of the row you changed and you have access to the columns with the indexes ...

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow dgvRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
                  // do what u want here like 
int teste = Convert.ToInt32(dgvRow.Cells[1].Value);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I asked if there is a way to solve this without event handling